# Connecting two statements in controller

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Having problems with the combining of two statements in a controller. Both statements work but cannot get them working as one element.

First statement is to show data for a user when his username matches the logged on usersname
This works fine.

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var myrecords = db.Customers.Where(UserData => UserData.UserName.Equals
                (User.Identity.Name)).ToList();

        return View(myrecords);
    }
```

Second statement is for connecting tables and showing the data. This works fine

```
  var caradverts = db.CarAdverts.Include(c => c.BodyType).Include(c => c.Car).Include(c => c.Colour).Include(c => c.Customer).Include(c => c.EngineSize).Include(c => c.fuel).Include(c => c.SalesPlan).Include(c => c.Transmission).Include(c => c.year);



        return View(caradverts.ToList());
```

Now the trouble is connecting both statements into one so it only shows the data for the user logged on.

Any advice welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var caradverts = db.CarAdverts
                   .Include(c => c.BodyType)
                   .Include(c => c.Car)
                   .Include(c => c.Colour)
                   .Include(c => c.Customer)
                   .Include(c => c.EngineSize)
                   .Include(c => c.fuel)
                   .Include(c => c.SalesPlan)
                   .Include(c => c.Transmission)
                   .Include(c => c.year)
                   .Where(c => c.Customer.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                   .ToList();
```

Do you really need all of these `Include` statements though? It looks like most of them refer to plain primitive properties and not related entities.

Also because most likely in the first case you want data from a *single* user I would rewrite your query like this:

```
 var userRecord = db.Customers
                    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

Then update your model/view accordingly to deal with a single `Customer` record and not a collection.

Comment: For what it's worth, most of those `Include`s are completely redundant. If one of them refers to a navigation property, it's needed. But calling `ToList` will force EF to load the entity properties.